# Adding a button to select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, selectize.js

I'm currently using selectize.js for my dropdown and I would like to add a button at the end of the option list like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvEA4.jpg)

I tried adding a span into the select group but it doesn't show up in the dropdown. How should I change my code to allow a button at the end of the option like shown in the picture?

```js
    $('#client').selectize();
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
            <label>Client</label>
            <select id="client" type="text">
                <option value="0">Add New Client</option>
                <option value="1">Client 1</option>
                <option value="2">Client 2</option>
                <option value="3">Client 3</option>
            </select>
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="clear_addon">Clear</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: You can't, not with an *actual* select element at least. One, you cannot put any other tag besides an `option` inside of a select tag. Two, you cannot find the height of the 
select dropdown menu browser element, which means you wouldn't be able to find the "bottom" to create an absolute positioned button. You will need to use a custom dropdown like the one in the picture you provided. [select2](https://select2.org/) is a plugin that converts your select element into a pretty dropdown.

Comment: render it in `.innerHTML` after using selectize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the plugin's `html` and append a button after the items list:

```
$('.selectize-dropdown').append('<button id="clear_addon">Clear</button>');
```